# CSV file advanced parsing

Tags: c, csv

I have a problem with parsing a .csv file. I have a `struct world` defined like this:

```
typedef struct world
{
    char worldName[30];
    int worldId;
    char *message;
    char **constellationArray;
    struct world *next;
} tWorld;
```

And I have a .csv file designed like this (so the 'c' is for 'semi-Colon'):

```
worldId;worldName;message;constellationArray
1;K'tau;Planeta pod ochranou Freyra;Aquarius;Crater;Orion;Sagittarius;Cetus;Gemini;Earth
2;Martin's homeworld;Znicena;Aries;Sagittarius;Monoceros;Serpens;Caput;Scutum;Hydra;Earth
3;...
```

The task seems simple: write a method `loadWorlds(char *file)`. Load the file and parse it. The number of constellations is not guaranteed. Each new line signals a new world and I have to create a linked list of these worlds. I have a rough idea of doing this, but I can't make it work. I have a method called `tWorld *createWorld()` which is implemented as such:

```
tWorld *createWorld() {
    tWorld *world;
    world = (*tWorld)malloc((sizeof(tWorld)));
    return world;
}
```

I have to use this method inside my loadWorlds(char *file). Plus I have to serialize them into the linked list with this:

```
if (*lastWorld == NULL){
    *lastWorld = nextWorld;
}else{
    (*actualWorld)->next = nextWorld;
}
*actualWorld = nextWorld;
```

But I don't know when to use it.  This is my rough sketch of `loadWorlds(char *file)`:

```
void loadWorlds(char *file)
{
    FILE *f;
    char text[30];
    char letter;
    tWorld *lastWorld = NULL, *actualWorld = NULL, *world;

    //f = fopen(file, "r");

    if(!(f = fopen(file, "r")))
    {
        printf("File does not exist! \n");
        while(!kbhit());
    }
    else
    {
        while(!(feof(f)) && (letter = fgetc(f))!= '\n')
        {

            if((znak = fgetc(f)) != ';')
            {

            }

        }
    }
}
```

I would be grateful for any ideas to make this work.

Comment: See [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong) for one set of problems.  You should probably be using `fgets()` to read lines and then scan them for your semicolon field separators — using `strcspn()` or `strpbrk()` or `strtok_r()` or `strtok_s()` — or, perish the thought, as a last resort, `strtok()`.

Comment: yes, and `fgets()` will keep the trailing `\n` for you to detect (although it's not clear if each line you listed also has a `\n` in addition the one you explictly mentioned in the first line, in which case the first line has two newlines, and `fgets()` will read that as two separate lines).

Comment: Your `createWorld()` function doesn't do enough for you; you need it to make sure that the elements of the structure are appropriately initialized.  You might be OK with using `calloc()` instead of `malloc()`, or you might assign values to the various fields.  It should probably error check for 'out of memory' and exit if that problem occurs.  You need to read lines with `fgets()`; you need to split them on the semicolons (or the newline).  Your data structure needs to keep track of how many constellations are in the current list somehow; I'd use two counts, number allocated and number used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question **"How do I parse this file?... (Plus I have to serialize them into the linked list)"** is a non-trivial undertaking when considered in total. Your **"How do I parse this file?"** is a question in its own right. The second part, regarding the linked list, is a whole separate issue that is not at all explained sufficiently, though it appears you are referring to a singularly-linked-list. There are as many different ways to approach this as there are labels of wine. I'll attempt to provide an example of one approah to help you along.

In the example below, rather than creating a single static character array `worldName` within a `tWorld` struct where all other strings are dynamically allocated, I've changed `worldName` to a `character pointer` as well. If you must use a `static array of chars`, that can be changed easily, but as long as you are allocating the remainder of the strings, it makes sense to allocate for `worldName` as well.

As to the `parsing` part of the question, you can use any number of library functions identified in the comments, or you can simply use a couple of `pointers` and step through each line parsing each string as required. Either approach is fine. The only benefit to using simple pointers, (aside from the learning aspect), is avoidance of repetative function calls which in some cases can be a bit more efficient. One **note** when parsing data from a line that has been dynamically allocated is to **make sure you preserve the starting address for the buffer** to insure the allocated memory can be properly tracked and freed. Some of the library functions clobber the original buffer (i.e. `strtok`, etc.) which can cause interesting errors if you pass the buffer itself without, in some way, preserving the original start address.

The function `read_list_csv` below parses each line read from the `csv` file (actually `semi-colon separated` values) into each of the members of the `tWorld` struct using a pair of character pointers to parse the input line. `read_list_csv` then calls `ins_node_end` to insert each of filled & allocated `tWorld nodes` into a `singularly-linked circular linked-list`. The parsing is commented to help explain the logic, but in summary it simply sets a starting pointer `p` to the beginning, then using an ending pointer `ep` checks each character in the line until a semi-colon `;` is found, temporarily sets the `;` to `\0` (nul) and reads the string pointed to by `p`. The temporary `\n` is replaced with the original `;` and the process repeats beginning with the following character, until the line has been completely parsed.

The `linked-list` part of your question is somewhat more involved. It is complicated by many `linked-list examples` being only partially explained and usually equivalently correct. Further, a `linked-list` is of little use unless you can add to it, read from it, remove from it, and get rid of it without leaking memory like a sieve. When you look at examples, note there are two primary forms linked-lists take. Either `HEAD/TAIL` lists or `circular` lists. Both can be either `singularly` or `doubly` linked.  `HEAD/TAIL` lists generally use separate pointers for the list start or `HEAD` and the list end or `TAIL` node (generally set to `NULL`). `circular` lists simply have the end node `next` pointer point back to the beginning of the list. Both have their uses. The primary benefit to the `circular` list is that you can traverse the list **from** any node **to** any other node, regardless where you start in the list. (since there is no `end-node`, you can iterate through all nodes starting from any node).

The example below is a `singularly linked circular list`. It provides functions for creating nodes, inserting them into the list, counting the nodes, printing the entire list, removing nodes from the list, and deleting the list. Importantly, it frees all memory allocated to the list.

Go through both the `parsing` part of the example and the `linked-list` part of the example and let me know if you have questions. While the list implementation should be fairly solid, there may be some undiscovered issues. The datafile used for testing as well as the sample output is shown following the code. The code expects the datafile as the first argument and an optional (zero based) node to delete as a second argument (default: node 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXL 256
// #define wName 30

typedef struct world
{
    // char worldName[wName];
    char *worldName;
    int worldId;
    char *message;
    char **constellationArray;
    struct world *next;
} tWorld;

/* allocate & populate node */
tWorld *create_node (int wid, char *wnm, char *msg, char **ca);

/* insert node into list */
tWorld *ins_node_end (tWorld **list, int wid, char *wnm, char *msg, char **ca);

/* read data from file fname and add to list */
tWorld *read_list_csv (tWorld **list, char *fname);

/* return the number of nodes in list */
size_t getszlist (tWorld *list);

/* print all nodes in list */
void print_list (tWorld *list);

/* free memory allocated to tWorld list node */
void free_node (tWorld *node);

/* (zero-based) delete of nth node */
void delete_node (tWorld **list, int nth);

/* delete tWorld list & free allocated memory */
void delete_list (tWorld *list);

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input. Usage: %s <filename> [del_row]\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    char *fname = argv[1];
    tWorld *myworld = NULL;             /* create pointer to struct world   */

    read_list_csv (&myworld, fname);    /* read fname and fill linked list  */

    printf ("\n Read '%zd' records from file: %s\n\n", getszlist (myworld), fname);

    print_list (myworld);               /* simple routine to print list     */

    int nth = (argc > 2) ? atoi (argv[2]) : 2;
    printf ("\n Deleting node: %d\n\n", nth);
    delete_node (&myworld, nth);        /* delete a node from the list      */

    print_list (myworld);               /* simple routine to print list     */

    delete_list (myworld);              /* free memory allocated to list    */

    return 0;
}

/* allocate & populate node */
tWorld *create_node (int wid, char *wnm, char *msg, char **ca) 
{
    tWorld *node = NULL;

    node = malloc (sizeof *node);
    if (!node) return NULL;

    node-> worldId = wid;
    node-> worldName = wnm;
    node-> message = msg;
    node-> constellationArray = ca;

    return node;
}

/* insert node into list */
tWorld *ins_node_end (tWorld **list, int wid, char *wnm, char *msg, char **ca) 
{
    tWorld *node = NULL;
    if (!(node = create_node (wid, wnm, msg, ca))) return NULL;


    if (!*list) {    /* if empty, create first node */
        node-> next = node;
        *list = node;
    } else {         /* insert as new end node */
        if (*list == (*list)-> next) { /* second node, no need to iterate */
            (*list)-> next = node; 
        }
        else                           /* iterate to end node & insert    */
        {
            tWorld *iter = *list;      /* second copy to iterate list     */
            for (; iter->next != *list; iter = iter->next) ;
            iter-> next = node;        /* insert node at end of list      */
        }
        node-> next = *list;           /* set next pointer to list start  */
    }

    return *list;   /* provides return as confirmation  */
}

/* read list from file fname and add to list */
tWorld *read_list_csv (tWorld **list, char *fname)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen (fname, "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: file open failed for '%s'\n", __func__, fname);
        return NULL;
    }

    /* allocate and initialize all variables */
    char *line = calloc (MAXL, sizeof *line);
    char *p = NULL;
    char *ep = NULL;
    char *wnm = NULL;
    int wid = 0;
    int lcnt = 0;
    char *msg = NULL; 
    char **ca = NULL;
    size_t idx = 0;

    while (fgets (line, MAXL, fp))      /* for each line in file    */
    {
        if (lcnt++ == 0) continue;      /* skip header row          */

        p = line;
        idx = 0;
        ep = p;
        size_t len = strlen (line);     /* get line length          */
        if (line[len-1] == '\n')        /* strip newline from end   */
            line[--len] = 0;

        while (*ep != ';') ep++;        /* parse worldId            */
        *ep = 0;
        wid = atoi (p);
        *ep++ = ';';
        p = ep;

        while (*ep != ';') ep++;        /* parse worldName          */
        *ep = 0;
        wnm = strdup (p);
        *ep++ = ';';
        p = ep;

        while (*ep != ';') ep++;        /* parse message            */
        *ep = 0;
        msg = strdup (p);
        *ep++ = ';';
        p = ep;

        ca = calloc (MAXL, sizeof *ca); /* allocate constellationArray */
        if (!ca) {
            fprintf (stderr, "%s() error allocation failed for 'ca'.\n", __func__);
            return NULL;
        }
        while (*ep)                     /* parse ca array elements  */
        {
            if (*ep == ';')
            {
                *ep = 0;
                ca[idx++] = strdup (p);
                *ep = ';';
                p = ep + 1;
                /* if (idx == MAXL) reallocate ca */
            } 
            ep++;
        }
        if (*p) ca[idx++] = strdup (p); /* add last element in line */

        ins_node_end (list, wid, wnm, msg, ca); /* add to list      */
    }

    /* close file & free line */
    if (fp) fclose (fp);
    if (line) free (line);

    return *list;
}

/* return the number of nodes in list */
size_t getszlist (tWorld *list) {

    const tWorld *iter = list;  /* pointer to iterate list  */
    register int cnt = 0;

    if (iter ==  NULL) {
        fprintf (stdout,"%s(), The list is empty\n",__func__);
        return 0;
    }

    for (; iter; iter = (iter->next != list ? iter->next : NULL)) {
        cnt++;
    }
    return cnt;
}

/* print all nodes in list */
void print_list (tWorld *list) {

    const tWorld *iter = list;  /* pointer to iterate list  */
    register int idx = 0;
    char *stub = " ";

    if (iter ==  NULL) {
        fprintf (stdout,"%s(), The list is empty\n",__func__);
        return;
    }

    for (; iter; iter = (iter->next != list ? iter->next : NULL)) {
        printf (" %2d  %-20s  %-20s\n", 
                iter-> worldId, iter-> worldName, iter-> message);
        idx = 0;
        while ((iter-> constellationArray)[idx])
            printf ("%38s %s\n", stub, (iter-> constellationArray)[idx++]);
    }
}

/* free memory allocated to tWorld list node */
void free_node (tWorld *node)
{
    if (!node) return;

    register int i = 0;

    if (node-> worldName) free (node-> worldName);
    if (node-> message) free (node-> message);
    while (node-> constellationArray[i])
        free (node-> constellationArray[i++]);
    if (node-> constellationArray)
        free (node-> constellationArray);

    free (node);
}

/* (zero-based) delete of nth node */
void delete_node (tWorld **list, int nth)
{
    /* test that list exists */
    if (!*list) {
        fprintf (stdout,"%s(), The list is empty\n",__func__);
        return;
    }

    /* get list size */
    int szlist = getszlist (*list);

    /* validate node to delete */
    if (nth >= szlist || nth < 0) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s(), error: delete out of range (%d). allowed: (0 <= nth <= %d)\n", 
                __func__, nth, szlist-1);
        return;
    }

    /* create node pointers */
    tWorld *victim = *list;
    tWorld *prior = victim;

    /* if nth 0, prior is last, otherwise node before victim */
    if (nth == 0) {
        for (; prior->next != *list; prior = prior->next) ;
    } else {
        while (nth-- && victim-> next != *list) {
            prior = victim;
            victim = victim-> next;
        }
    }

    /* non-self-reference node, rewire next */
    if (victim != victim->next) {
        prior-> next = victim-> next;

        /* if deleting node 0, change list pointer address */
        if (victim == *list)
            *list = victim->next;
    } else {  /* if self-referenced, last node, delete list */
        *list = NULL;
    }

    free_node (victim);  /* free memory associated with node */
}

/* delete tWorld list */
void delete_list (tWorld *list)
{
    if (!list) return;

    tWorld *iter = list;  /* pointer to iterate list  */

    for (; iter; iter = (iter->next != list ? iter->next : NULL))
        if (iter) free_node (iter);
}
```

**input test data file:**

```
$ cat dat/struct.csv

worldId;worldName;message;constellationArray
1;K'tau;Planeta pod ochranou Freyra;Aquarius;Crater;Orion;Sagittarius;Cetus;Gemini;Earth
2;Martin's homeworld;Znicena;Aries;Sagittarius;Monoceros;Serpens;Caput;Scutum;Hydra;Earth
3;Martin's homeworld2;Znicena2;Aries2;Sagittarius2;Monoceros2;Serpens2;Caput2;Scutum2;Hydra2;Earth2
4;Martin's homeworld3;Znicena3;Aries3;Sagittarius3;Monoceros3;Serpens3;Caput3;Scutum3;Hydra3;Earth3
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/struct_ll_csv dat/struct.csv 1


 Read '4' records from file: dat/struct.csv

  1  K'tau                 Planeta pod ochranou Freyra
                                       Aquarius
                                       Crater
                                       Orion
                                       Sagittarius
                                       Cetus
                                       Gemini
                                       Earth
  2  Martin's homeworld    Znicena
                                       Aries
                                       Sagittarius
                                       Monoceros
                                       Serpens
                                       Caput
                                       Scutum
                                       Hydra
                                       Earth
  3  Martin's homeworld2   Znicena2
                                       Aries2
                                       Sagittarius2
                                       Monoceros2
                                       Serpens2
                                       Caput2
                                       Scutum2
                                       Hydra2
                                       Earth2
  4  Martin's homeworld3   Znicena3
                                       Aries3
                                       Sagittarius3
                                       Monoceros3
                                       Serpens3
                                       Caput3
                                       Scutum3
                                       Hydra3
                                       Earth3

 Deleting node: 1

  1  K'tau                 Planeta pod ochranou Freyra
                                       Aquarius
                                       Crater
                                       Orion
                                       Sagittarius
                                       Cetus
                                       Gemini
                                       Earth
  3  Martin's homeworld2   Znicena2
                                       Aries2
                                       Sagittarius2
                                       Monoceros2
                                       Serpens2
                                       Caput2
                                       Scutum2
                                       Hydra2
                                       Earth2
  4  Martin's homeworld3   Znicena3
                                       Aries3
                                       Sagittarius3
                                       Monoceros3
                                       Serpens3
                                       Caput3
                                       Scutum3
                                       Hydra3
                                       Earth3
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. This was very helpfull and educating!

Comment: hi. linked list, insert/update seems very intuitive for me. but I have problem understand delete. in here. I found it's hard to understand function `delete_node`, example, a linked list `1->2->3->4->5` if I delete 3  then somehow I  have to link 2 with 4? but I cannot see the same connection in here(Or I don't get it).

Comment: @jian - this is a special kind of list called a *Circular* list. It is slightly more involved than a normal linked list because it allows you to iterate from any node around the list, not having to start at `head` and ending at `tail`. With this kind of list when there is only 1 node, then `next` pointer points to itself (self-referencing). So when you insert or delete you have to check (1) if list is empty, (2) if only one node (self-referencing) or (3) more than one node where the last `next` points back to the first instead of being `NULL`.

Comment: @jian for a normal singly-linked list, it's far better to go with something like [Singly Linked List of Integers (example)](https://pastebin.com/R2AewR3A)